# mysql how to update a table by auto-incrementing a column

Tags: mysql, sql

A MySql 5.3 table with 100K rows has a primary key.

There is also an integer column which is not part of the key. I would like to update this column to contain a unique number for the table. E.g. for the first record it should contain 1, for the second 2 etc.

This could as well be an auto-increment column, but MySql does not allow auto-increment on non-key columns. I don't want this column to be part of the key, because of the way it gets populated from a file etc.

So how such a query would look like?

Comment: -1. You want a unique key that represents a sequence based on the number of rows inserted and it's not the primary key? What on earth are you doing with the database?!

Comment: First, to preserve the order of loaded records (from external db). Second, to save space. The original primary key is long and I am making many references to this table. So instead of repeating several key columns in each reference, I'd just create on column and use it in references. Some other imported tables are already referencing using the long primary key - so both keys must stay.

Comment: So you want to reference certain rows in a table? Why wouldn't you just reference the primary key, instead of creating a brand new column to duplicate the function of the primary key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to do something like this, but a possible solution is this:

```
set @rownum:=0;
update <table> set column = @rownum:=rownum+1 order by <field>
```

Comment: Thanks! the @rownum:=@rownum+1 is also possible to use directly in LOAD DATA INFILE in SET clause