# How to update a VARCHAR value with a simple increment using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In order to clean a WordPress database, I'm currently attempting to update the `post_name` VARCHAR field with an simple incremented value.

After having tested a [specific solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197837/set-rownum-shows-null-in-rowno-column) given by @gmoliv (I would prefer simple numbers according to selected rows), I tried to adapt [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865898/mysql-how-to-update-a-table-by-auto-incrementing-a-column) given by @gianluca, *i.e.*:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_name = @rownum:=rownum+1
WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="post"
ORDER BY post_date
```

Unfortunately, I get an error *#1054 Unknown column 'rownum' in 'field list'*

Thank you if anyone can enlighten me on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the MySQL variable as a column name in your UPDATE query.

Before:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_name = @rownum:=rownum+1
WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="post"
ORDER BY post_date
```

After (see line 3):

```
SET @rownum:=0;
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_name = @rownum:=@rownum+1
WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="post"
ORDER BY post_date
```

Comment: To complete this answer, I think that to set a VARCHAR value, a simple increment may not be perfect. Possibly prefer a query like:
`SET @rownum:=0;
 UPDATE wp_posts
 SET post_name = CONCAT('n-', @rownum:=@rownum+1)
 WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="post"
 ORDER BY post_date`